# Adding a JavaScript file to a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 2.  I have a master page and a view that uses this master page.  I have to use a javascript file for this view only, and not for the other views.  What is the best way to add a javascript file to this view?  What I currently did was to add the javascript file at the top in my content tag.  Is this the best way to do it?  I did it as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="cntMain" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">

     <script src="../../Scripts/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

The content place holder for this content tag in my master page is in a div, so it is complaining that a script tag can not be in a div, and underlines it in green.  So I am assuming that there is another decent way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your master page where you want the script to appear

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptsContent" runat="server" />
```

and add this to your view

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptsContent" runat="server">
       <script src="../../Scripts/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The content place holder for this content tag in my master page is in a div

Move the ContentPlaceHolder to the `head` section in your master page and use it as normal. Note, although you declare this in the master page, you don't have populate it in any/all of your views.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```